# Downloads from Bamboo server are slow, how can I debug this?

Tags: windows, http, slow-connection, bamboo

I have a Windows box running Bamboo, a continuous integration server. I can download files from it over HTTP, but they're really slow, like 80 kbps slow. I don't have any speed issues copying files between the machine and network shares.

What are some steps I can take to debug this problem? I really don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We migrated Bamboo to run under Tomcat on Windows Server 2008 and the problem went away.